# Change constants defined in interface

Tags: java, interface, constants

I have interface which hosts constants needed by my application. I would like to be able to change then during runtime, becuase they depends on various conditions. I have created small class, which will have method for handling constant. In this class I have implemented interface with constant, I have access to them but I cannot change their content. I know constants are supposed to be stable without changing, but still, is there any way how to change them?

Thx

**Edit:**

Of course this is not from my head, I need to change ready made library, which should depend on Android manufacturer. And I am asking if there is some other way then reimplementing it.

Comment: The words "change" and "constant" don't really play very nicely with each other. Hence the term "variable" (a thing which can *vary*).

Comment: The downvotes seem inappropriate, like someone's just reading the title and not reading the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

The words "change" and "constant" don't really play very nicely with each other. Hence the term "variable" (a thing which can *vary*). ;-)

You may be able to achieve what you're looking for using [`final` variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4). These are variables which can only be assigned *once*. You couldn't put them on an `interface`, but you could make them members of a singleton that gets initialized and sets the finals to the appropriate runtime value.

Answer (score 1):

constants are exactly what they say on the tin!

You may want to try not using contants and reading into static, private, public and so on!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler usually inlines compile time know constants.  This means even if you change the value using reflection, it won't always change the places where the constant is used.

A solution to this is to make your "constants" dynamic. e.g.

```
interface Constants {
    int MAX_VALUE = Integer.getInteger("max.value", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    String USER_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home");
}
```